# Setting a DependencyProperty to application resource causes memory leak

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a custom UserControl (MyView) that contains one DependencyProperty called Header. This UserControl is part of several other UserControls (Views). It is resolved through DataTemplate

```
<!-- SomeView's resources -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel">
  <vw:MyView Header="{StaticResource myViewHeader}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Some of the view that are containing MyView are passing the same resource for MyView's Header. For this reason I have places myvIewHeader in the globally available resources (application resources).

Having the resource globally available causes memory leaks, since MyView never gets garbage collected.

However, if I place Header resource inside a container's (ex SomeView's) resources, then everything gets properly cleaned up.

In order for MyView to not cause memory leaks when using globally available resource for Header, I need to set Header to null in MyView's Unloaded event:

```
this.Unloaded += (s, e) =>
  {
    this.SetValue(HeaderProperty, null);
  };
```

My question is this: **why** is this happening, and am I doing things **properly**, or I should achieve this in some **other** (better) way?